# Swift: Implementing Find-or-Create Efficiently

Tags: json, swift, core-data

So I set up some data from an API to create a managed object, How do I determine whether the managed object already exists (in my example, every object has a unique id), and create it if it does not.

```
// set up core data
        var appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!


        // Get data from API
        let urlPath = "http://www.example.com"
        let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let getMovies = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {
            data, response, error -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                println(error)
            } else {

                // Parse the JSON data from API
                var moviesResult: NSDictionary! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSDictionary

                if let subjects = moviesResult["subjects"] as? [[NSObject:AnyObject]] {
                    var movies = [[String:NSString]()]
                    var movie:AnyObject
                    var newMovieItem:NSManagedObject
                    // Loop through the arrays returned by API to get each movie
                    for (var i = 0 ; i < subjects.count ; i++) {
                        // Initialize the movies array
                        movies.append([String:NSString]())
                        movie = subjects[i] as NSDictionary
                        movies[i]["title"] = movie["title"] as? NSString
                        movies[i]["id"] = movie["id"] as? NSString
                        newMovieItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Movies", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! NSManagedObject
                        newMovieItem.setValue(movies[i]["title"], forKey: "title")

                        newMovieItem.setValue(movies[i]["id"], forKey: "id")

                        context.save(nil)
                    }
                    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Movies")
                    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
                    var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)
                }
            }
        })
        getMovies.resume()
```